# How to give flex items equal width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I would like the first and last elements to have the same width. How to do it?

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  </div>
</main>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7nz07sqn/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `flex: 0 0 auto` to the *middle* div (so that it occupies as much width as its contents have) and `flex: 1` for the other two divs (adding `border`s for illustration)

Note that this solution *assumes* the *middle div* has a fixed width (you've given your `input` a fixed `width`) - see demo below:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
main > div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
main div:first-child, main div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}

main div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,

  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the first and last elements equal width, just give them `flex: 1`.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}

main > div:first-child,
main > div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  </div>
</main>
```

This tells the first and last items to consume equal distributions of the free space in the container.

Because the middle div (with the input) is occupying 200px of width, the siblings with `flex: 1` share the remaining space (100% - 200px).

The `flex: 1` rule is a shorthand for `flex: 1 1 0`, which breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

The first and last divs were not equal width to begin with because the initial setting for `flex-basis` is `auto`. This means that items are sized based on the length of their content.